# What algorithm should I use for searching a collection of phrases?

Tags: algorithm, search

I have about 1,000 items for the user to search through.  I am trying to find the best search algorithm for my use case.  I am currently using the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), but it does not suit my needs for the following reason.

Things user can search for: "Pool", "Pool Table", "Table"

When the user types in "Pool", I want the results to come back with both "Pool" and "Pool Table".  But with the Levenshtein Distance algorithm, I can only return "Pool", because "Pool Table" is not a close match.

One solution is for me to run the Levenshtein Distance algorithm on each word, and just use the word with the closest match.  But I don't know if there is a better way, and I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

I am not concerned about performance at this time.  I have a collection of strings that I am iterating through one at a time.  All of the strings are stored locally, and I need to stay offline.  I am using C#.  (I can manipulate the data in any way I please, though.)

Some code to show my current approach:

```
List<string> GetSearchResults(string searchTerm)
{
    var results = new List<string>();
    foreach(string item in collectionOfItems)
    {
        int levenshteinDistance = CalculateLevenshteinDistance(searchTerm, item);
        if(levenshteinDistance <= 3)
        {
            results.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

What is the best search algorithm for a user to search a collection of strings that meets my above criteria?

Comment: Are you using a database? or are you building this from scratch?

Comment: @Evert I have an array of strings that I am looping through.  Performance is not a concern at this time.  I will update the question.

Comment: If you really don't want to reinvent the wheel, you could for example just import everything in MySQL and use a `FULLTEXT` index. I just don't really know if that satisfies your requirement or if you want to do everything from within your script. It's a complex subject that have many solutions with varying trade-offs.

Comment: @Evert Ah, gotcha.  I need to stay offline for my search.  The strings the user is searching for is all local.  Updating question again.

Answer (score 0):

- Preprocess the phrases
- Split the search term in words and find matches with single words
- find all the phrases that contains any word that matches

Pseudo code

```
// prepare phrases
dict wordsPhrases
dict phrasewords 
dict words
for(phrase in collectionOfItems) 
  parts = split(phrase)
  words.append(parts)
  phrasewords[phrase] = parts;
  for (word in parts)
    wordsPhrases[word].append(phrase)


string searchTerm
List<string> searchTerms = split(searchTerm)
List<string> searchHits

// hits for each
for (word in searchTerms)
  searchHits.append(GetSearchResults(word)) // uses words instead of collectionOfItems for Levenshtein

// optional makeUnique(searchHits)

List<string> result
for (word in searchHits)
  result.append(words[word]) // add all phrases that contain word

// Alternatively rank the result
dict result
for (word in searchHits)
  for (phrase in wordsPhrases[word])
    result[phrase]++

sorted = sort(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for this interesting question. I have a proposal.

Given a search input `word`, we iterate over the entire array and find all entries that are `<related>`, sorting them by `<relevance>`. This sorted result set will be returned as the output.

Here, `<related>` and `<relevance>` are functions that determine, perhaps unsurprisingly, how related and relevant each entry is with respect to `word`. You are free to design your own logic.

One low-hanging implementation is as follows:

1. An entry is *related* to `word` if `word` is a substring of the entry. Then, "Pool Table" is *related* to "Pool".
2. An entry is *highly relevant* if `word` occurs earlier in the entry, and *less relevant* if it occurs later in the entry. That is, we weight the relevance of each entry based on the index of the first occurence of `word` within that entry. For example, "Pool Table" is more relevant than "Table pool" if `word` is "Pool".

A more flexible (but more complicated) implementation could look as follows:

1. An entry is related to `word` if `word` is a subsequence of the entry.
2. An entry is *highly related* to `word` if the sum of the indices of the subsequence of `word` in entry is small, and *less relevant* otherwise.